# Attachment of external content - forcing although X-Frame-Option=SAMEORIGIN

Tags: html, iframe, x-frame-options

I read more in the Internet, but I didn't managed to find solution to this problem:
Is it possible to attach some external content in case of sending `X-Frame-Option=SAMEORIGIN` by server ?

I know that `<iframe>` can't be used, however maybe there exists some another way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to show another page's contents within your website if they are setting the HTTP header `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`. That header says that the page can only be embedded on pages on the same domain name.

However, if you are running your own server-side application (i.e. using PHP, Node.js, etc), you can scrape the website on your server, and then display whatever info you needed from the other site that way. It will be more work this way, and you probably won't be able to perfectly replicate how everything appeared on the source site, but it's the only route you've got. I suggest googling "scraping" + the name of your server-side language/environment to learn how to do this.